# spring boot serving static pictures from file dir

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, file

So im making a spring boot project and i want users to be able to upload pictures into a directory relative to the project folder of my app. I am able to save the pictures in "/diplomna/uploads" with diplomna being also the folder containing the project. I enabled the resource path:

```
@Configuration

public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {


@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    exposeDirectory("diplomna", registry);
}
 
private void exposeDirectory(String dirName, ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    Path uploadDir = Paths.get(dirName);
    String uploadPath = uploadDir.toFile().getAbsolutePath();
     
    if (dirName.startsWith("../")) dirName = dirName.replace("../", "");
     
    registry.addResourceHandler("/" + dirName + "/**").addResourceLocations("file:/"+ uploadPath + "/");
}
}
```

I also enabled it in spring security

```
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/images/**","/css/**","/diplomna/**", "/js/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .permitAll();
}
```

but when I try to load the picture in a page with

```
<td><img src="'+data[i].path+'" class="img-responsive" alt="..."></td>
```

with data[i].path=/diplomna/uploads/logPic2.png

I get the error
GET http://localhost:8080/diplomna/uploads/logPic2.png 404

Both the project and the pictures are located in my D disc any suggestions on why it is not working are apreciated.

Comment: Can you try printing the `uploadPath` variable (or use a debugger)? I don't think it will contain the full path to where the image is located on disk.

Comment: ah sry, I already fixed the problem just didn't have the time to close the question. I was saving the pictures on the wrong path it had nothing to do with he loading itself.

Comment: You can answer your own question and mark it as resolved so it does not remain as unanswered here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer when I went through the whole process of saving and loading the file.

The problem had nothing to do with how I was loading the pictures. The method that was saving the files was saving them in the wrong place and that's why they couldn't be loaded.